# Javascript global array object can't be read

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having a few issues and I think it is because of the way I'm declaring an array. I'm using jQuery and I want to declare a global array so I can use its items inside my functions. The way I'm doing it now, when I do try to use the items in a function, they are limited. I did a console log of the array and it seems to show that it has stuff in it (even the stuff that I want) but then when I perform jQuery functions on those items it tells me

> Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Additionally, I've not used arrays much in JS, just in C++, so perhaps there's an issue with my syntax? Here is a rough copy of the code I have:

```
var pigs = new Array();
pigs[0] = $('#foo');
pigs[1] = $('#bar');

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(pigs);
    var topCoord = pigs[0].offset().top;
});
```

Comment: Does $('#foo') exists ?

Comment: `$('#foo')` wont return an element before `document.ready`

Comment: first of all, do you have '<div id="foo"></div>' and '<div id="bar"></div>'

Comment: and write pigs[0] = $('#foo');
pigs[1] = $('#bar');
 inside document ready

Comment: I hope you enjoy JS?! The more beautiful way to do Arrays is for example: var pigs = []; -- then in document.ready just do pigs.push( $('#foo') ) to fill it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `$('#foo')` and `$('#bar')` both return empty jQuery objects. You should wait for the DOM to be ready before querying it :

```
var pigs = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
    pigs[0] = $('#foo');
    pigs[1] = $('#bar');
    console.log(pigs);
    var topCoord = pigs[0].offset().top;
});
```

Comment: If I assign those values in that function, will I still be able to use those objects and values in other functions? In other words, if I change it within that function, it will be changed globally as well right?

Comment: Yes sir. Welcome to Javascript ;-)

Comment: @mavsman Sure, because the array is defined inside the global scope.

Comment: Haha sadly, I've been using it for 6 months and never used arrays, yikes. Thanks for the help, it worked like a charm